# What are steps for generating fsm code in C or C++ with NunniFsm?

Tags: fsm

I have seen that,there is free source fsm generator named NunniFsm .For that you can refer

http://www.nunnisoft.ch/nunnifsmgen/en/home.jsp .I have downloaded the source package and

examples.The readme explain the steps to create fsm for java projects,But doesn't explains for C

and C++.If anybody used it before please explain the steps ,how I  can use it for C and C++

projects.

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Ok .I got it as the

## java -jar NunniFSMGen.jar -?

specifies that

java -jar NunniFSMGen.jar [options] configurationFile
  options:
    -?              : show usage
    -V              : show version
    -i              : show program info
    -v              : verbose
    -o {java|c|c++} : language generated (default: java)
    -p              : package (default: read from file else ^generated')
    -n              : basename (default: read from file else 'Context')
  configurationFile : file containing the FSM transition table

So by using option -o we can generate the code for either c ,c++ or Java.

Comment: hey I found that the dog example in c++ doesn't compiles as it gives error as /tmp/ccm4P3Hj.o: In function `DogFSM::DogFSM(void*)':
DogFSM.cxx:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `DogSleepState::instance()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: can anybody please help?